# How can I get an average Isoline using Here Maps API

Tags: rest, here-api

I'm using the isoline functionality from here Maps' REST API to get all the area within a given time from a particular store.

For this, I'm making a Query like this:

```
private $_url="https://isoline.route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?";

$here_cd = env('HERE_CODE');
    $here_id = env('HERE_ID');
    $data = array(
        'app_id' => $here_id,
        'app_code' => $here_cd,
        'rangetype' => 'time',
        'range' =>$sec,
        'mode' => 'fastest;car',
        'destination' => (string)$lat.','.(string)$lng                                
    );

$full_url=$this->_url.http_build_query($data);
```

I want a General/Average drivetime polygon, which does not depend on the current traffic.

I'm not passing the `arrival` parameter.

Is it possible to create a General/Average drivetime polygon or isoline which is not extremely dependent on the current traffic situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [TrafficMode](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-routing-mode.html) to disabled during the request to remove traffic from the isoline calculation.

For example:

```
&mode=fastest;car;**traffic:disabled**;motorway:-3
```